# echo <<<_END not working

Tags: php, html, sql

I have the code bellow embedded in my php tags, however it does not read the html, does anyone know why? Any help would be appreciated.

```
echo <<<_END
<pre>
<form action = "sqltest.php" method = "POST">
Author <input type = "text" name = "author" />
Title <input type = "text" name = "title" />
Category <input type = "text" name = "category" />
Year <input type = "text" name = "year" />
ISBN <input type = "text" name = "isbn" />
<input type = "submit" value = "Add Record" />
</form>
</pre>

_END;
```

Comment: you have nothing on the line (not even space) before _END; ? you get no error?

Comment: I first thought it's bash ;) Works for me, I've just tried.

Comment: No error, and no changed it to no space before _END; I think for some reason its reading it as a string in my text editor if that helps?

Comment: Strange, must be problem with the text editor, i copied the source code from above in my question to replace the code and it worked. Strange as i originally copied the code from the text editor to here. Thanks anyway guys/girls.

Comment: Perhaps you had a space before the closing string? That would probably break it. Also, boooooo to whoever downvoted with no comment.

Comment: @Jake.Hoskins, btw what text editor where you using?

Comment: Perhaps, i definitely did move it so there was no space, maybe the editor automatically indented it thanks anyway everyone!

Comment: @Jake.Hoskins: What's the problem here?  It works for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/P2uvgg

Comment: No problem any more, must have been the whitespace before, but was confused because i deliberately didn't allow whitespace. Anyway its fixed now thanks anyway @rocket

Comment: @Jake.Hoskins: If you want, you can answer your own question, and state that it was the whitespace :-)

Comment: @Rocket I will in 7 hours as reputation is to low :-)

Answer (score 5):

The problem was with the whitespace, be careful when using the <<<_END statement as your default text editor may indent it. There must be no whitespace.

Comment: A simple mistake. It's a shame HEREDOC/NOWDOC doesn't allow indented ending tags - breaking the indentation is annoying.