# Why echo <<<_END and _END; not working, still no whitespace

Tags: php, echo

[image]

It has no whitespaces but still no working? how to overcome that?

Comment: what is this PHP? echo isn't a sufficient tag

Comment: have you looked at similar answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525456/echo-end-not-working

Comment: Yes, the author told that problem was with whitespaces, but forgot to mansion where exactly. I did not find in my code any of inappropriate ones, have no idea how to make it works. I work in NetBeans 8.1

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.13

Answer (score 0):

Ok,I solved the issue by one way like:  after my _END; in the beginning of next line I just typed another _END;

And as you see on the pic [the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jELP8.png) it works now, and then I deleted previous one, and it still work. I think it's a bug of NetBeans